# How to make Visual Studio 2010 stop just once for each unhandled exceptions in debugging mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

I have checked both "Stop on thrown exceptions" and "Stop on user-unhandled exceptions" checkboxes.

When an unhandled exceptions is thrown, Visual Studio stops and shows the exception message. This is by design.

But if I then press F5 to continue, Visual Studio stops again, at the same line, showing the same exception message. I have to hit F5 a second time to continue.

Notice that Visual Studio stops once if I check only "Stop on user-unhandled exceptions" (but of course, I need to check both checkboxes...).

This begin to be annoying. Any way to change this ? Thanks :)

Comment: This is where the usual advice is applicable: only use exceptions for exceptional conditions.  You can filter specific exception types by expanding the node in the Debug + Exceptions dialog and unticking the Thrown checkbox.

Comment: @Hans, you are right. Problem : this is not my code and when I change something, I want to be sure I do not create a new bug somewhere. Since some exceptions are swallowed, I would miss them by just looking at the log files. Hence a systematic stop on exceptions. Thanks!